# Autostart Video using Fast-Video-View

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-view

I'm using  Fast-Video-View library to play videos but videos doesn't start auto someone need to press play button i need to make to show videos auto, I include exoplayer in my gradle

`videoview.start();`

doesn't work....

Here is my Fragment CODE

```
package com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import com.warnyul.android.widget.FastVideoView;

public class BenchFragment extends Fragment {

    private FastVideoView videoView;
    public  View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bench, container, false);
        FastVideoView videoView = (FastVideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bench);
        videoView.setMediaController(null);
        videoView.start();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.setVolume(0, 0);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have problem in your fragment, or you don't have correct path of your video because everything is okay in your FastVideoView code. Write down how are you setting your fragment to your Activity

Comment: i see  the video but i need to press play button to show the video instead of auto play

Comment: and then is it starting?

Comment: if i press play yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start `MediaPlayer` in `onPrepared()` Method,
Try this,

```
 videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bench);
    videoView.setMediaController(null);
    videoView.start();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.setVolume(0, 0);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```